# Python 3.5 invalid signature | Pepper robot

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, pepper

I'm using Python 3.5.10-slim-buster (Docker) with the Pepper robot from Softbank. The NAOqi version on the robot is 2.5.8 (taken from `/var/log/naoqi/servicemanager/system.Naoqi.log`).
I got qi v. 3.0.0 via pip.

I want to subscribe to events with

```py
pepper = qi.Application()
pepper.start()
session = pepper.session
memory = session.service("ALMemory")

def touch_event(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

subscriber = memory.subscriber("ALTouch/TouchChanged") # throws RuntimeError: Invalid signature
if subscriber:
    subscriber.signal.connect(touch_event)
```

Creating the session directly like in http://doc.aldebaran.com/libqi/api/python/session.html didn't work either.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

I've referenced this issue in https://github.com/aldebaran/libqi-python/issues/13.

tldr: The issue occurs most likely due to a missmatch between the NaoQi OS and the coresponding libQi library.
My workaround for this is to run my code directly on the pepper robot.

Even with the latest version of libqi and the fix from Victor (see
https://github.com/victorpaleologue/libqi-python/tree/47df0833c707cfd2a6a4c86765db423f319e029d)
it didn't work and resulted in the same error.

Comment: Hello, I tried to call memory.subscriber from a freshly rebuilt qi (3.0.0 and 3.1.0, in a Python 3.10) and it worked fine. Could you update your question with: how you installed qi, what is your host OS, and which NAOqi version your Pepper is running? Could you try creating a session directly? http://doc.aldebaran.com/libqi/api/python/session.html

Comment: I've updated the question. I also tried to build qi from the official repository and your repo with Python 3.10.6 on Ubuntu 22.04 but I couldn't get that to work. What was your setup to build qi?

Comment: I'm on MacOS 13.1, arm64, so I needed to patch the repo: https://github.com/victorpaleologue/libqi-python. I build it from its `pipenv shell` with this command: `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib/pkgconfig GOOGLETEST_VERSION=1.12.1 LIBQI_VERSION=3.0.0 BOOST_VERSION=1.81 python3 ./setup.py bdist_wheel`. It requires boost and openssl to be installed with `brew`. It works with a NAOqi 2.1 on a NAO.

Comment: Small update: Building qi 3.1.1 with Python 3.10.6 on Ubuntu 22.04 resulted in the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been a protocol breakage in libQi, that you can only spot on methods that returns QiObjects such as `ALMemory.subscriber`.

NAOqi 2.5.x has a libQi version around 1.8.x, and libQi 2.x is already incompatible with that. You are running a libQi 3.x, so you experience the issue too.

It is going to be hard to recompile [an old `libqi-python`](https://github.com/aldebaran/libqi-python/tree/release-2.5.2) for Python 3, so I recommend that you work around this issue by using the legacy `ALMemory.subscribeToEvent`.

To do that with libQi, you will need to register a service hosted on your client machine, and make sure it is accessible to the robot by listening on public addresses on the network:

```py
# Listen to public addresses on a random port,
# so that services registered from here are accessible.
session.listen("tcp://0.0.0.0:0")

# An object that will be registered as a service.
class MySubscriber:

    # It needs at least a callback to get ALMemory events.
    def onTouched(key, value):
        pass

subscriber = MySubscriber()

# Register it with an arbitrary name.
service_name = "MySubscriber"
session.registerService(service_name, subscriber)

# Subscribe and tell exactly which service and method to call back.
memory.subscribeToEvent("TouchChanged", service_name, "onTouched")
```

Also, note that [the right name of the event is `TouchedChanged`](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/sensors/altouch-api.html#TouchChanged) (no `ALTouch/` prefix).